# Howto upload a photo to AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, upload, content-type

I have an Android application and an App Engine server.
I would like to send a photo (content-type : image/jpeg) from the phone to the server.

I have found this code for the AppEngine part :

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);
        FileItemStream imageItem = iter.next();
        InputStream imgStream = imageItem.openStream();

        // construct our entity objects
        Blob imageBlob = new Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(imgStream));
```

However, these methods need a multipart/form-data content-type.
What can I do, because I would like a "image/jpeg" ?

Tkx

Comment: possible duplicate of [android to appEngine image content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854529/android-to-appengine-image-content-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the BlobStore:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html